scipy 1.14.1 breaks statsmodels 0.14.2
After installation of scipy 1.14.1 a previously viable Python program now fails.
The original program is more complex so here's a MRE:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        "Date": [0, 7, 14, 21, 28],
        "Value": [100, 110, 120, 115, 122]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    px.scatter(df, x="Date", y="Value", trendline="ols")

Here's the stack trace (username obfuscated):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/****/Python/Aug22.py", line 12, in <module>
    tl = px.scatter(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/express/_chart_types.py", line 66, in scatter
    return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py", line 2267, in make_figure
    patch, fit_results = make_trace_kwargs(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/express/_core.py", line 361, in make_trace_kwargs
    y_out, hover_header, fit_results = trendline_function(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/plotly/express/trendline_functions/__init__.py", line 43, in ols
    import statsmodels.api as sm
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/api.py", line 136, in <module>
    from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/recursive_ls.py", line 14, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel import (
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .simulation_smoother import SimulationSmoother
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/simulation_smoother.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .kalman_smoother import KalmanSmoother
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/kalman_smoother.py", line 11, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.representation import OptionWrapper
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/representation.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .tools import (
  File "/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/tools.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import (_initialization, _representation, _kalman_filter,
  File "statsmodels/tsa/statespace/_initialization.pyx", line 1, in init statsmodels.tsa.statespace._initialization
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/****/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/_representation.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_npy_cabs'

If I revert to scipy 1.14.0 this error does not occur.
Is there anything I can do that would allow me to run with scipy 1.14.1?
Platform:
macOS 14.6.1
python 3.12.5
Apple M2


Reverting to statsmodels 0.14.1 also seems to fix it.

Are you using pre-built binaries, or building from source? e.g. can you start from a fresh virtual environment, and post the output of pip when you install your dependencies?

@NickODell I use a traditional virtual environment where everything is installed with pip. I created a completely new venv and installed the minimal requirements to allow the MRE to run. That's how I was able to demonstrate that it's the latest scipy that breaks statsmodels. If I run pip install scipy==1.14.0 and re-run the MRE there is no error

Thanks for clarifying, however pip can both download pre-built wheels or build a wheel from source, so both are still possible.

This issue has been fixed in statsmodels 0.14.3. See https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/9333

Update: This issue has now been fixed in statsmodels 0.14.3.
The rest of this answer is of historical interest only.

This looks like a bug to me, so I filed issues against SciPy, statsmodels, and the statsmodels maintainer filed an issue against NumPy.
Here's a summary of what I've learned from those issues.
Cause of Problem
In NumPy 2.1.0, NumPy started marking certain functions with __attribute__((visibility("hidden")), with the effect that extensions built against NumPy would not re-export symbols exported by NumPy. The pull request doing this is here.
These are the cabs related symbols exported by NumPy prior to 2.1.0:
$ nm -gU venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-312-darwin.so | grep cabs             1 ↵
00000000000148c0 T _npy_cabs
000000000001487c T _npy_cabsf
0000000000014904 T _npy_cabsl

And after:
$ nm -gU venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.cpython-312-darwin.so | grep cabs

It stopped exporting _npy_cabs.
In SciPy 1.14.1, SciPy switched from being built against NumPy 2.0.1 to being built against 2.1.0.
As a consequence, it also stopped exporting the _npy_cabs symbol.
These are the cabs related symbols being exported prior to 1.14.1:
$ nm -gU venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-312-darwin.so | grep cabs     
000000000007c248 T _npy_cabs
000000000007c204 T _npy_cabsf
000000000007c28c T _npy_cabsl

And after:
$ nm -gU venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.cpython-312-darwin.so | grep cabs

It also stopped exporting _npy_cabs. (The npy stands for NumPy, so it is a little strange for SciPy to provide this function.)
Fix
In summary, you have three choices of ways to solve the problem.
Workaround #1
Downgrade SciPy from 1.14.1 to 1.14.0.
As a consequence, you would be missing these fixes.
Workaround #2
Downgrade NumPy from 2.1.0 to 2.0.1.
As a consequence, you would be missing these fixes and new features.
Workaround #3
Wait for a fix from statsmodels for the issue. They would need to adjust the way they are linking NumPy.
This has now been fixed in statsmodels 0.14.3.

Issue links: scipy statsmodels numpy

The last line is an "ImportError", so at first glance it looks like scipy was incorrectly built somehow. Two mac users reported similar mishaps here and here.
To ensure this is a similar enough problem :

check if other python programs fail (in the first link, an 'import numpy' caused the same error)
check the build logs for your last scipy version, looking for linking warnings such as :
ld: warning: ignoring file build/temp.macosx-11-arm64-3.8/libnpymath.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format)

Both solved their problem. Their solutions :

first guy had modified his $PATH to include some GNU binutils (specifically ranlib) that conflicted with apple's included version, and solved his problem by removing those from his $PATH ;
second guy had used brew to install a dependency (protobuf) and solved his problem by using conda instead.


I do not use either conda or brew (homebrew). protobuf 5.27.3 is installed in my virtual env. I have no idea where to find the build logs that you refer to

I guess it depends on what you use to manage your python environment. If you use a command line program (such as pip) it will usually print it on your terminal. You can save the logs by running '(your install or upgrade command) > some-log-file.txt 2>&1'  and then search 'some-log-file.txt' for clues.

This answer assumes that OP is building from source, which may not be the case if they're on a platform which SciPy provides pre-built binaries for.
